How is the sector disk layout of a GUID partition table with a logical=physical sector size of 4096 bytes
I would like to know how a disk having logical AND physical disk sector size of 4096 bytes (aka advanced format - AF) is organized using a GPT?
On a 512-byte sector drive (either logical=physical or in 512e emulation mode), this is:
LBA 0 = protective MBR, LBA 1 = primary GPT header, LBA 2..33 primary GPT. At the end of the disk, LBA_MAX-33..LBA_MAX-2 stores secondary GPT and finally LBA_MAX-1 is secondary GPT header. The first data partition (at least on Linux) is stored at LBA 2048 (1MB). So far, so good.
I do not have a full 4096-byte-sector drive at hand, so I do not know how e.g. gdisk organizes a logical/physical 4096 byte drive:

Do the protective MBR, the primary GPT header, the secondary GPT header occupy full 4096 bytes? I guess: yes.
We need 128 GPT entries with 128 bytes each = 16KB for the primary GPT and secondary GPT, so this fits into four (4) 4096 byte sectors. Correct?

In fact, LBA 0 is the protective MBR, LBA 1 is the primary GPT header, LBA 2..5 store the primary GPT, LBA_MAX-5..LBA_MAX-2 is the secondary GPT, LBA_MAX-1 is the secondary GPT header. For partition storage, LBAs 6..LBA_MAX-6 are usable. Is this correct or do I miss something here? Furthermore, can tell me someone how the protective MBR on a 4096 byte drive looks like? Do the four primary partitions also 'move' to the end of the MBR sector (now 4096 bytes)?
Thanks in advance.
Did not try a gdisk run because I do not have such a drive.
